# Watch latest mysql query without logging

Tags: mysql

Does the command line client of mysql allow me to listen to current queries?

So i would not need to turn on logging and can check the queries for the time, i am interested to it temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL version 5.1.16 or newer, you can temporarily enable the general query log and have it log to a table instead of a file. Then you can select from that table to get the latest query.

Here's an example:

```
-- capture current state
SET @old_general_log = @@global.general_log;
SET @old_log_output = @@global.log_output;

-- set log output to table instead of file
set global log_output = 'TABLE';
-- enable the general log
set global general_log = 'ON';

-- get the latest query, excluding my session
select * 
from mysql.general_log
where thread_id != connection_id()
order by event_time desc
limit 1;

-- revert to previous state when done
set global general_log = @old_general_log;
set global log_output = @old_log_output;
```

Comment: I worry that this solution will lead into troubles on my mysql server, with replication (slave) on some of the databases including the "mysql" DB with user table etc. any idea for this use-case?

Comment: The mysql.general_log table is not replicated. If you run those commands on a master DB, the slave(s) will be unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes login to mysql using `root` user then execute following query:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

you can enable query logging to a file and then use `tail -f file_name` linux command to view current queries. see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)

or you can also use linux command as:

shell> `watch -n1 'uptime ;  mysql -u root -p'your_password' test -e"show full processlist"'`

Comment: this does only show the currently running processes, and i am not fast enough to log them from there... another idea?

Comment: your shell line looked very promising; but again, this shows only the current queries (each second), not the last N queries. looks like there is no alternative to the logfiles or log table :-(

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL [manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html):

```
SHOW [FULL] PROCESSLIST;
```